# how to identify if checkbox is checked ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

When I'm getting E-mail message I can not identify which checkbox is checked.

My JS code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.post("submit.php", 
        {service1: $('#service1').val(), 
         service2: $('#service2').val(), 

        function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
    );

});
```

What should I add to my code to identify which is checked?
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you getting? What's your HTML markup?

Comment: `$('#service2').is(':checked')` will be true or false

Comment: I didn't see anything related to checkbox in your code..

Answer (score 0):

`$('#services1').prop('checked')` should do the trick.